# Best practices and tools for a big, extendible worklight enterprise application

Tags: templates, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to optimize my company's application.
Tha architecture at this time is composed of different folders (inside common folder) for different sections of the app (for example Managing Bills, Managing Canteen, Managing Events etc etc).
Every js and css are included in the first page of the application (login.html) because I'm using the simple page template of jQuery Mobile.

Now I'm considering to add some other components to make the app easier to mantain and maybe speed it a bit.

What do you think about:

- RequireJS to divide each section in a module so i can load only the javascript of a particular module at run-time instead of loading within login.html
- Inline @imports for CSS files to produce single composite CSS
- uglify.js to Minimize file sizes
- Handlebars.js to realize fragments of html reusable

Do you think is a good way of work for an application that will become greater by adding new sections?
Do you think of other tools?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very broad question. I think you're on the right track... I'll list some libraries that could be worth trying:

- [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) - Will give you the ability to have 'modules' and dynamically determine and load dependancies. Alternatively some people prefer patterns such as the [Revealing Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript), [jQuery Plugin Style](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) or [Common JS style](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) modules. For what it's worth I recommend Require.js.
- [Bower](http://bower.io/) is a package manager, you can use it to `bower install [package]`. They have a lot of packages [here](http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/) and you can also link it to [your own repo](https://github.com/bower/bower#configuration). This could be helpful for managing dependancies.
- [Uglify.js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) and [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) are both good for minifying your code. Remember that some minification configurations such as *advance mode* could break your code. Run tests against the minified version of your source code.
- [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) is good for doing JavaScript unit tests. There are many other alternatives like [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/), which is what the [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) guys use.
- [Lodash](http://lodash.com/) is another (faster) implementation of [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) that will provide a lot of utility methods for working wit arrays, objects,  functions, etc. It also [includes templating support](http://lodash.com/docs#template). There's a good talk by the author [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpPy4f_SeEk).
- There a MV* JavaScript frameworks that could help more than [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (DOM+AJAX+Animations) or [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) (Mostly UI) such as: [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org), [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) and [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/).
- For UI you may want to checkout [Adobe's topcoat repository](https://github.com/topcoat/topcoat) and [website](http://topcoat.io/). There's also [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) which allow you do to [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) out of the box. If you're set on jQuery Mobile I personally like this [Flat theme](https://github.com/ququplay/jquery-mobile-flat-ui-theme).
- [JSDoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) and [YUIDoc](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/) are good alternatives for documenting your JavaScript code.

I have no idea how many of those tools will interact inside Worklight Applications. It should be fine, since Worklight doesn't impose a certain set of JavaScript libraries you have to use. However, I haven't personally tried most of them inside Worklight Applications.

Comment: Very thank you for your response, it's a very nice and structured one.
So you don't advise me nothing like handlebars.js or mustache.js, do you think lodash can do the template task better?

Comment: I think [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) and [lodash's template function](http://lodash.com/docs#template) are all very capable. For what it's worth, Handlebar.js is probably the one with the most features. I would not discourage anyone from using any of those libraries.

Comment: By the way, if my answer was helpful you should consider accepting it (clicking on the green checkmark below the up/down arrows). You can un-accept if a better answer shows up later.